# most occurring value in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector file with 1000 values. All the values were generated using Random function between 0-1.

```
x <- runif(100,min=0,max=1)
x
  [1] 0.84620011 0.82525410 0.31622827 0.08040362 0.12894525 0.23997187 0.57177296 0.91691368 0.65751720
 [10] 0.39810175 0.60632205 0.26339035 0.93543618 0.09662383 0.35147739 0.51731042 0.29151612 0.54411769
 [19] 0.73688309 0.26086586 0.37808273 0.19163366 0.62776847 0.70973345 0.31802726 0.69101574 0.50042561
 [28] 0.20768256 0.23555818 0.21015820 0.18221151 0.85593725 0.12916935 0.52222127 0.62269135 0.51267707
 [37] 0.60164023 0.30723904 0.81990231 0.61771762 0.02502631 0.47427724 0.21250040 0.88611710 0.88648546
 [46] 0.92586513 0.57015942 0.33454379 0.03572245 0.68120369 0.48692522 0.76587764 0.55214917 0.31137200
 [55] 0.47170307 0.48639510 0.68922858 0.73506033 0.23541740 0.81793240 0.17184666 0.06670039 0.55664270
 [64] 0.10030533 0.94620061 0.58572228 0.53333567 0.80887841 0.55015406 0.82491114 0.81251132 0.06038019
 [73] 0.10918904 0.84011824 0.33169617 0.03568364 0.07703029 0.15601158 0.31623253 0.25021777 0.77024833
 [82] 0.88588620 0.49044305 0.10165930 0.55494697 0.17455070 0.94458467 0.43135868 0.99313733 0.04482747
 [91] 0.53453604 0.52500493 0.35496966 0.06994880 0.11377845 0.71307042 0.35086237 0.04032254 0.23744845
[100] 0.81131033
```

Out of all these values in the vector, I need to find the most occurring value(Or close to that). I'm new to R and have no idea what this. Please help?

One approach I have - Divide all the values in a certain ranges and find the frequency distribution. But will it be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to analyze the distribution of the numbers could consist in plotting a histogram and adding  an approximate probability density distribution.
This can be done with the `ggplot2` library:

```
set.seed(123) # used here for reproducibility
x <- runif(100) # pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 1
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(as.data.frame(x),aes(x=x, y=..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill="lightblue",colour="grey60",bins=50) + 
  geom_density()
```

[image]

The value of bins specified in `geom_histigram()` is the number of bars in the histogram. You may want to try to change this value to obtain a different representation of the distribution.

**OR**

You could use base `R`and plot a simple histogram:

```
hist(x)
```

[image]

There you can also change the bin width (see `breaks`), but the default might be sufficient to show the concept.

You can identify which bin in this histogram has the most entries with

```
> hist(x)$mids[which.max(hist(x)$counts)]
#[1] 0.45
```

Which in this case means that most values occur near a value of 0.45 (the middle of the bin describing the range between 0.4 and 0.5).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I want just a range or number as my result and not the plot or histogram? Thanks in advance

Comment: The value will depend on the bin size. Typically, each number appears only once, so there is no answer to the question "which is the number that appears most often". But if you specify an interval (the bin size), then a certain amount of numbers will fall into that range.

Comment: @AkshayJangra Please check the revised version. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: thanks for the reworked version. I'll work this in my script and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
set.seed(12)
x <- runif(100,min=0,max=1)
n <- length(x)
x_cut<-cut(x, breaks = n/4)
which(table(x_cut)==max(table(x_cut)))
```

The result depends on the `breaks` value you set. This is an alternative to using a histogram if you don't need one.

Comment: Can I automate breaks ? Depending on the size of observations?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer! just divide the length of the vector (n) by some number.

Comment: I'm getting the results such as -  (0.00084614,0.0009478] 
                     5
Can you explain me the results?

Comment: That means that in this interval there are 5 values and this is the interval with the most values.

Comment: Can I use probability distribution in this vector to get desired result?

Comment: what do you mean? @AkshayJangra

Answer (score 0):

To really get just the most occurrent value, or when using discrete data as input, you could simply create a `table`, sort the results and return the highest value:

```r
values <- c("a", "a", "c", "c", "c")

names(sort(table(values), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
#> [1] "c"
```

Breaking it down:

```r
# create a table of the values
table(values)
#> a c 
#> 2 3

# sort the table descending on number of occurrences
sort(table(values), decreasing = TRUE)
#> c a 
#> 3 2

# now only keep the first value
sort(table(values), decreasing = TRUE)[1]
#> c 
#> 3

# so the final line:
names(sort(table(values), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
#> [1] "c"
```

If you're feeling like wanting to do fancy stuff, create a function that does this for you:

```r
get_mode <- function(x) {
  names(sort(table(values), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
}

get_mode(values)
#> [1] "c"
```